# React-Router V2, V4 - How can I use "router" of react-router V2 in react-router V4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I see the "this.props.router.push" function in React Router v2.
How can I use this function in React Router V4?

For example:

```
setFilter(query) {
  this.props.router.push({ pathname: this.props.location.pathname, query });
}
```

Comment: Just use `this.props.history.push()`

Comment: @sertsedat, thank you very much.

Comment: @konekoya, thank you very much.